# Proof of properties of convex polygons

Tags: geometry, reference-request, convex-geometry

Let $P$ be a polygon on a plane. I want to show the equivalence of the following assertions:

1. $P$ is convex;
2. every internal angle of $P$ is strictly less than $\pi$;
3. $P$ is an intersection of a finite number of closed half-planes;
4. every diagonal of $P$ lies inside of $P$;
5. for every side $AB$ of $P$, $P$ lies in a single half-plane with respect to $AB$.

Some of the implications are trivial, i.e, $1\Longrightarrow 4$, $1\Longrightarrow 2$ and $4 \Longrightarrow 5 $, $3\Longrightarrow 1$.

Surely this question is not new, however I wasn't able to find a reference with a proof.

Comment: How do you define a polygon and its interior ? The proof will depend on the definition.

Comment: I define polygon as a bounded figure on a plane which boundary is a finite number of non-intersecting segments. I guess, I believe in the polygonial version of a Jordan curve theorem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the book https://bmm.ru/books/details/418737/ (in russian).

[image]

[image]